# Subgraph node overlaps with regular - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'd like to have beautiful state machine without any thinking of it's layout. I also need some node grouping with description of the group. So, I wrote the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, fit, graphdrawing, graphs, automata, shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, snakes, petri}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered, force}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout, grow' = right,
         nodes = {ellipse, draw}]
  {
    s -> {s1, s2, s3};
    s1 -> s1v2;
    s1v2 -> s1v1 ->[bend right] s1v2;
    s1v2 -> s1v3t;
    s2 -> s2v1 -> s2v2 ->[bend right] s2v1;
    s2v2 -> s2v3t;
    s2 -> s2v3 -> s2v2t;
    s3 -> s3v2 -> {s3v3t, s3v1t};
    NS1[draw, rectangle] // {s1v2, s1v1};
    NS2[draw, rectangle] // {s2v1, s2v2}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, subgraph nodes is overlapping with the regular ones. (If you want to see it for yourself, compile code with `lualatex` - it's required for TikZ 3 graph lay out algorithms). I think it's a consequence of them being created after graph has been laid out (see `pgf` manual). What can I do?

Comment: Okay, the only (for now) present answer from @esdd is good, but (if there are TikZ experts here) is there more automated way? That would be completely beautiful :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can enlarge the `sibling sep` either for the whole graph

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, fit, graphdrawing, graphs, automata, shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, snakes, petri}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered, force}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout, grow' = right,
         nodes = {ellipse, draw},
         sibling sep=3em,% enlarge the sibling sep to 3em
        ]
  {
    s -> {s1, s2, s3};
    s1 -> s1v2;
    s1v2 -> s1v1 ->[bend right] s1v2;
    s1v2 -> s1v3t;
    s2 -> s2v1 -> s2v2 ->[bend right] s2v1;
    s2v2 -> s2v3t;
    s2 -> s2v3 -> s2v2t;
    s3 -> s3v2 -> {s3v3t, s3v1t};
    NS1[draw, rectangle] // {s1v2, s1v1};
    NS2[draw, rectangle] // {s2v1, s2v2}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or only for `s1v3t`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, fit, graphdrawing, graphs, automata, shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, snakes, petri}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered, force}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout, grow' = right,
         nodes = {ellipse, draw},
        ]
  {
    s -> {s1, s2, s3};
    s1 -> s1v2;
    s1v2 -> s1v1 ->[bend right] s1v2;
    {[sibling sep=6em]s1v2 -> s1v3t};% enlarge sibling sep
    s2 -> s2v1 -> s2v2 ->[bend right] s2v1;
    s2v2 -> s2v3t;
    s2 -> s2v3 -> s2v2t;
    s3 -> s3v2 -> {s3v3t, s3v1t};
    NS1[draw, rectangle] // {s1v2, s1v1};
    NS2[draw, rectangle] // {s2v1, s2v2};
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anything more automatic?